# Make a textbox appear next to selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 1 radio button group with 2 radio buttons options.
I want to make a textfield appear next to it if the radio button is checked.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbPhs/)

I tried using jQuery and the .css function, but it does not work.
I want people to be able to type their website URL in a textfield next the the radio button they select. If I select the first one, a textbox will appear next to it. If I switch to the other one, the textbox will disapear and appear next to the 2nd radio button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `display` property instead of `visibility`:

```
input[type=text] {
  display: none
}
```

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
   $('input[type=text]').hide()
   $(this).parent().next().show()
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TbPhs/9/)

1. [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
2. [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
3. [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
4. [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: Very well done - it works with any number of fields without modification, too!

Comment: This is good, but you shouldn't set the input boxes to hidden in the css. You should hide them by default on page load in the javascript so that this can degrade into a usable form with javascript turned off.

Comment: @Jeff yes, you are correct, adding a class at page load is better than preventing users with disabled js to see the inputs.

Comment: a brilliant approach you have showed,and when I'm trying to implement it in my jsp page.I'm unable to implement it.inside a division I'm using this piece of code.Any inputs if you want to share.

Comment: @undefined, may I request you to have a look at a different css, jquery question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137378/div-above-another-div-but-should-scroll-beneath-the-later-one

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
//hide both by default
$('#siteCourtier').hide();
$('#siteAgence').hide();

$('#courtierRadio').change(function() {
   if($('#courtierRadio').is(':checked'))
   {
       $('#siteCourtier').show();
       $('#siteAgence').hide();
   }
});

$('#agenceRadio').change(function() {
   if($('#agenceRadio').is(':checked'))
   {
       $('#siteAgence').show();
       $('#siteCourtier').hide();
   }
});
```