# div above another div, but should scroll beneath the later one

Tags: jquery, html, css

there is a `div` (namely `div_fixed`) which is  fixed in position. Another `div` namely `other_content` is beneath the `div_fixed`. The `other_content` div has a `padding-top` property  so that when the page is scrolled only the `other_content` is scrolled beneath the fixed div.

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BCRPa/)

HTML :

```
<div class="div_fixed">FIXED</div>
<div class="other_content">
    content goes here<br/>
    content goes here<br/>
    content goes here<br/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
     div { color: #fff }
        .div_fixed { position: fixed;  
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 

    
    }

.other_content { 
background: #f00; 
height: 5000px; 
color: #fff; 
padding-top: 100px; 

margin:0 auto;

}
```

But I want the non-fixed div to stay upon the fixed div and want the non-fixed div to disappear just beneath its upper edge i.e. position of the non-fixed div's upper edge will remain fixed but it's content will start disappearing on page scroll just the way it happened when it was staying beneath the fixed div.

So i had a little edit in the html ( just 2 breaks) before the non-fixed div :

```
    <div class="div_fixed">FIXED</div>
<br><br/>
        <div class="other_content">
            content goes here<br/>
            content goes here<br/>
            content goes here<br/>
        </div>
```

The addition in css is:

```
  .fixed_div{
    
    z-index:-1;
    }
    
    .other_content{
    
    
    width:60%;
    z-index:99099900;

    
    }
```

But the upper edge of the non-fixed div does not stay at the position I want.

How to achieve that ?

**EDIT** :

suppose I add a background image  for the non-fixed `div`. Is it possible that part of  background image of the fixed  `div` over which the other div will scroll will have a `z-index` higher than that of the non-fixed `div` ? Will the problem be solved in that way ?

**EDIT2**

Let use suppose that `fixed_div` is the header, `other_content` is the **content body** of a webpage. Let us add a footer `div` with id `footer`. No scroll should be present in `other_content`. `other_content` should scroll when the page is scrolled.

Comment: not based on this question,I want to achieve the effect shown in your fiddle ,for some reason I can't seem to achieve it,can u help me?

Comment: it seems i forgot to set background color for the fixed element fixed it

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you're looking for. You'll want to position the fixed div in a `fixed` fashion, but the second div doesn't need special positioning. Just give it a `margin-top:100px` where `100px` is the height of the fixed div.

The trick is to use `z-index` and to add `position:relative;` to the content div

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KyP8L/3/

```
.div_fixed{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;    
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ff0;
    z-index:500;
}
.other_content {
    width:60%;    
    background:#0ff;
    margin-top:100px;
    z-index:600;
    position:relative;
}
​
​
```

Comment: what change did it make ? width of the `other_content` div should be 60%. In that case the non-fixed div does not seem to stay on the fixed one ?

Comment: `other_content` should stay above `fixed_div`. jsfiddle does not show that.

Comment: When you say above, you mean closer to the user on the z-axis? Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/KyP8L/3/  - the trick is to use `z-index` and to add `position:relative;` to the content div.

Comment: now this is 'above'. But the `other_content` should be staying on the `fixed_div` and the upper edge should be a bit down to that of the `fixed_div`  .

Comment: You'll need to explain what you want a bit better, or show me an example or illustration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22114/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-dutchie432)

Comment: the jsfiddle solution if taken in pc browser as a normal web page, it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to wrap the content div in another container with a fixed position.

For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="div_fixed">FIXED</div>
<div class="fixed_container">
    <div class="other_content">
        content goes here<br/>
        content goes here<br/>
        content goes here<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed_container {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    top:30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
    z-index:10; }

.other_content { position: absolute; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xmKMs/

Comment: what about the disappearance of the upper edge of the `other_content` in the expected way ?

Comment: why `padding-top:100px` for the `other_content` ?

Comment: That's just what you had in your original example.  That could be removed if necessary.

Comment: try reducing the height and increasing the amount of content: http://jsfiddle.net/xmKMs/

Comment: the scroll bar in for the scrolling div is not wanted. When the web page is scrolled the scrolling div should also scroll... Looking for the solution